# What is the syntax for a factor-by factor interaction in stata (11)?

Tags: r, syntax, statistics, stata, interaction

I've got two factor variables, one is coded as numeric and the other is coded as a character string.  Call them `C` and `N`.  I want to include their interaction in a regression (which would expand them into dummies.  In R I would code

`lm(y~as.factor(C)*as.factor(N))`
or

```
library(plm)
C = as.factor(C)
N = as.factor(N)
plm(y~C:N, index=c('C','N'), effect="twoways")
```

In stata, I want to do something like

```
xtset C N
xtreg y c*N, fe
```

what is the syntax for doing this?

Comment: Have a look at the answer for your real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string variable you must convert to numeric. `encode` is one option. Then use Stata's factor variable notation (i.e. `#`). A nonsensical example:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto
describe
keep price mpg make

encode make, gen(make2)
regress price mpg c.mpg#i.make2
```

Factor variable notation was introduced precisely with Stata 11.

Type `help factor variables`, `help encode`, for the details.

Note: I have not tried to *translate* your R code to Stata.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately it didn't end up helping my real problem:

`xtabond yield ss1#i.vl ss6#i.vl ss5#i.vl ss4#i.vl ss3#i.vl ss2#i.vl ss1-ss6 t L1.yield L2.yield, two robust
interactions not allowed`

Any idea how to get around this?  PLM in R is bad about dropping collinear dummies

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed, it is useful to simplify the problem when posting to a site/forum like Stack Overflow, but it still needs to be representative. It looks like in this case it was too far away from the real thing.

Answer (score 2):

`#` doesn't work in `xtabond`. See the similar question [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-05/msg00522.html) on Statalist. Here is quick and dirty way to solve that in Stata for your real problem:

```
webuse abdata
tabulate ind,gen(ind) # industry dummies 
tabulate year,gen(yr) # this is not needed because it is already in the dataset
egen ind_year=group(ind year) # interaction of year and ind or gen ind_year=ind*year works
tabulate ind_year,gen(ind_year) # interaction dummies
xtabond n l(0/1).w  ind2-ind9 yr1977-yr1984 ind_year2-ind_year80
```

Note: in `R` you can use `interact` for `group` in `Stata`.